# Debugging XSL-FO overflows

Tags: xslt, pdf-generation, xsl-fo, apache-fop

My PDF generation is throwing a bunch of overflow warnings 
Namingly

```
INFO: An fo:table  (No context info available) is wider than the available room in inline-progression-dimension. Adjusting end-indent based on overconstrained geometry rules (XSL 1.1, ch. 5.3.4)
WARNING: Line 1 of a paragraph overflows the available area by 2165 millipoints. (No context info available)
INFO: An fo:table  (No context info available) is wider than the available room in inline-progression-dimension. Adjusting end-indent based on overconstrained geometry rules (XSL 1.1, ch. 5.3.4)
WARNING: No space remaining to distribute over columns.
WARNING: Line 1 of a paragraph overflows the available area by 2165 millipoints. (No context info available)
WARNING: Content overflows the viewport of the fo:region-before on page 1 in block-progression direction by 68746 millipoints. (No context info available)
INFO: Rendered page #1.
```

**How can I display "viewports" or populate "context info"** to get some sense of where things go wrong?

Comment: I worked around the issue by moving content from header to body and enlarging table columns. I am still interested in the debugging aspect.

Comment: You are using Apache FOP? What would your desired output be like? There's already some info in the output, after all.

Comment: Yes Apache FOP it is. I would like to get a line number or some text field pointing to the culprit element

Comment: Strange, it usually does that - gives a position right there where it says "(No context info available)" for you...

Comment: E.g., one of my outputs looks like this: "An fo:table  (See position 1:92986) is wider than the available room in inline-progression-dimension. ..." Do you work with absolute positioning? Can you provide a complete example?